# How to know that I select the cell is same as I have already selected of UITableView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem related to know the selected row is same or different. actually I am using core data and I want to update the row if I select the same cell of tableview.I know how to save,fetch,update and delete the object of core data.
For updating I am using a code is

```
NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];
[favoritsGrabbed setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Key"];
NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

On objectAtIndex I want that index which I have already selected before.And if it is not then it insert in core data.I try using flag but I am getting just a index in string which I have recently press.I want to compair it with all the IndexPath. How to do this??  can anybody give me any example. How to use NSPredicate and how to compare it.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

use NSPredicate for that, just assign a predicate on the result.
Wherever you are making a fetch request assign it a predicate.

for example: request.predicate.

after that you will get to know whether that exist or not in your database.
if you found any result update that else insert it as new item.

Hope you find it.

Comment: but I have some value same in database.

Comment: so maintain a unique id every time you save the data, so that you can easily retrieve the data according to the id and that will be unique for every record.

Comment: @AmamGangurde can yo share some code hear. How to do this??

Comment: @AmamGangurde I have use IndexPath.row as I unique id and save it in core data and retrieve it in array.But I am now getting how to compare it.

Comment: let resultPredicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)

Comment: don't use index path as id because every time the tableView is reloaded the indexpath wil be altered if you delete that entry